# Nuxt/ Vue - the html and js files it generates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just started using Nuxt for server side rendering. It seems like a great framework. But I don't like about it is it generates lots of ugly html markups, js links, and the css is basically being dumped into the html directly. Also, you see lots of `data-`s. It seems that you have no control of them at all (that worries me!). For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-n-head-ssr data-n-head="">
  <head>
    <meta data-n-head="true" charset="utf-8"/><meta data-n-head="true" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="description" name="description" content="Nuxt.js project"/><title data-n-head="true">Users</title><link data-n-head="true" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/manifest.1dd9a3883f67d40b9aa7.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/common.992cf40ea79f7d7937d8.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.2d1407798eb328e5c249.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/layouts/default.1360f17fdf8a6083917d.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/pages/users.a5ea843f780a24b7dfd7.js" as="script"><link rel="prefetch" href="/_nuxt/pages/index.3c2e71cd997494896cb8.js"><link rel="prefetch" href="/_nuxt/pages/users-name.353da70d66b2cb18c1c9.js"><link rel="prefetch" href="/_nuxt/pages/about.7e9c73cd5e6253d976d6.js"><link rel="prefetch" href="/_nuxt/layouts/dark.9d852c7e76764cd94b7c.js"><link rel="prefetch" href="/_nuxt/pages/tasks.67c8259c9b53f68ea9a3.js"><style data-vue-ssr-id="5e853cdc:0">body,html{background-color:#fff;color:#000;letter-spacing:.5px;font-family:Source Sans Pro,Arial,sans-serif;height:100vh;margin:0}footer{padding:20px;text-align:center;border-top:1px solid #ddd}a,a:focus,a:hover,a:visited{color:#000}.logo{width:100%;height:auto;max-width:400px;max-height:289px}.layout-enter-active,.layout-leave-to{-webkit-transition:opacity .5s;transition:opacity .5s}.layout-enter,.layout-leave-to{opacity:0}</style><style data-vue-ssr-id="c6f373dc:0">.progress[data-v-5b643829]{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;height:2px;width:0;-webkit-transition:width .2s,opacity .4s;transition:width .2s,opacity .4s;opacity:1;background-color:#efc14e;z-index:999999}</style><style data-vue-ssr-id="59c3f703:0">.title[data-v-2941d5fc]{margin:30px 0}.users[data-v-2941d5fc]{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.user[data-v-2941d5fc]{margin:10px 0}</style>
  </head>
  <body data-n-head="">
    <div id="__nuxt" data-server-rendered="true"><div class="progress" style="width:0%;height:2px;background-color:black;opacity:0;" data-v-5b643829></div><section class="container" data-v-2941d5fc><img src="/_nuxt/img/logo.a04e995.png" alt="Nuxt.js Logo" class="logo" data-v-2941d5fc><h1 class="title" data-v-2941d5fc>
    USERS
  </h1><ul class="users" data-v-2941d5fc><li class="user" data-v-2941d5fc><a href="/users/jona" data-v-2941d5fc>
        jona
      </a></li><li class="user" data-v-2941d5fc><a href="/users/jon" data-v-2941d5fc>
        jon
      </a></li><li class="user" data-v-2941d5fc><a href="/users/jonas" data-v-2941d5fc>
        jonas
      </a></li></ul></section></div><script type="text/javascript">window.__NUXT__={"layout":"default","data":[{"users":[{"_id":"59a53db03a35535198135b15","id":null,"name":"jona"},{"_id":"59a53ded3a35535198135b17","id":null,"name":"jon"},{"_id":"59a574afd5bc922f3dbf8b68","id":null,"name":"jonas"}]}],"error":null,"serverRendered":true};</script><script src="/_nuxt/manifest.1dd9a3883f67d40b9aa7.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/layouts/default.1360f17fdf8a6083917d.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/pages/users.a5ea843f780a24b7dfd7.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/common.992cf40ea79f7d7937d8.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/app.2d1407798eb328e5c249.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is plain ugly to me:

```
<div id="__nuxt" data-server-rendered="true"><div class="progress" style="width:0%;height:2px;background-color:black;opacity:0;" data-v-5b643829></div><section class="container" data-v-2941d5fc>
```

Why do I need `id="__nuxt"` for?

How can I build all the js files into one file - not sure if this is possible?

How can I not to embed the entire css into the html?

How is this going to effect SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`data-v-*` attributes**?

They come from the vue CSS loader if you use `scoped` css.

**Why do I need id="__nuxt" for?**

Because it mounts Vue app to DOM element which is `<div id="__nuxt"></div>`

**How can I build all the js files into one file - not sure if this is possible?**

Why would you do that? Nuxt tries to help you avoid performance issues. That's why it seperates.

**How can I not to embed the entire css into the html?**

You can extract css check out the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extractcss) but again it will extract what's common not all css.

**How is this going to effect SEO?**

It won't.

--

You can try to extend webpack config for your needs(bundling js, extracting css etc.). Check out the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extend).

Edit: Also you can check other popular frameworks like [Next](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) or [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org). All of them trying to follow best practices. Server side rendered output is not meant to be pretty infact it's uglified(minified) on purpose.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I would love it have the html `minified` if i can do that :-D

Comment: The reason why I picked Nuxt is that I don't like React. Writing code in React is very ugly.

Comment: `Why would you do that? Nuxt tries to help you avoid performance issues. That's why it seperates.` I thought minify and uglify all js files into a single file is better in performance, no?

Comment: @teelou It sort of depends because when modules get too large that also can have a negative impact on performance so we split them up into several smaller requests to avoid such troubles.

Comment: @teelou `I thought minify and uglify all js files into a single file is better in performance` as @nblackburn said it depends and i recommend you to read: [JavaScript Start-up Performance](https://medium.com/reloading/javascript-start-up-performance-69200f43b201) by addyosmani.

Comment: @teelou Next and Gatbsy were example about the SSR output. They have smiliar output like Nuxt.

Comment: @Mesut glad to know that. Save my time investing in them lol thanks for the tip! :-D Personally, I don't like react as it is a pain reading the code writing in it.